# spring data rest post sub-resource

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using `spring data rest` and want to post a new resource and its sub-resource.Both of them are new resource so there is no link pointing to either of them.In fact,the following json is  a reasonable json I think to post the new resource and its sub-resource .

here is a json represents one new student.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "sex": "man",
  "details": [
    {
      "detailKey": "weight",
      "detailValue": 130
    },
    {
      "detailKey": "height",
      "detailValue": 175
    },
  ]
}
```

`details` of this student is sub-resource and not exist in databases.

how I post John and his `details` at the same time(in one json or in one request),or there is a more proper way to do this?

PS:
`Student` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student", catalog = "test")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String sex;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Student() {
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Student(String name, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "sex")
    public String getSex() {
        return this.sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

}
```

`StudentDetails` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details", catalog = "test")
public class StudentDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer id;
    private Integer studentId;
    private String detailCode;
    private String detailValue;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public StudentDetails() {
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public StudentDetails(Integer studentId, String detailCode,
            String detailValue) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.detailCode = detailCode;
        this.detailValue = detailValue;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "student_id")
    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "detail_code")
    public String getDetailCode() {
        return this.detailCode;
    }

    public void setDetailCode(String detailCode) {
        this.detailCode = detailCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "detail_value")
    public String getDetailValue() {
        return this.detailValue;
    }

    public void setDetailValue(String detailValue) {
        this.detailValue = detailValue;
    }

}
```

`StudentDetails` is used to customize student's information.

both of id is auto increment,and I want to post one new student and his details info in the same request(I think it is friendly to the user)

Comment: can you share your pojo and your rest repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring doesn't have first-class support for sub-resource (JAX-RS does). You will either have to do 2 calls from the client, or handle it on the server. It's not clear from your question how `details` can be a resource; it has no id. Weight and height don't uniquely identify a person. It seems your design is wrong, or you need to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Two calls will be a proper solution,but I am curious how to handle it on the server.According to [Spring Data REST - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html),The only way I know is close save method and write a `StudentController` which handles POST and PATCH request.Do you have similar code to post resource and its new sub-resource in one request

Comment: @john what's the point of extracting some fields as student details? I don't see any reuse.

Comment: Actually,this is a test demo,but I think it's meaningful.Sometimes there are some information can be customized with key-value .Thus,user can add more information,such as weight:130 and height:175

Comment: @john adding key-value doesn't mean it has to be a sub resource. That doesn't make sense. Consider name. If you wanna update name, you make  a PUT or PATCH request for the Student resource; same goes for any other attribute. Like I said before, your design is questionable.